# How to replace the name of a field in a body of an email

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer

I have a questionnaire form on my website that emails me answers submitted by visitors. One of the questions asks users for the best contact time (morning, afternoon, evening) The name of that select class is contact-time.

Currently in the body of the email, it's displayed as Contact-time just like I named it in the html form. I want it to display as Contact Time.

How can I build the body of the email so that it displays contact-time as Contact Time while still being able to fetch the value from select class named contact-time? I've looked through pretty much all questions regarding this and couldn't find any relevant information.

PHP code that builds the email and then sends it

```
<?php
  function constructEmailBody () {
    $fields =  array("name" => true, "email" => true, "address" => true, "phone" => true, "contact-time" => true);
    $message_body = "";
    foreach ($fields as $name => $required) {
      $postedValue = $_POST[$name];
      if ($required && empty($postedValue)) {
        errorResponse("$name is empty.");
      } else {
        $message_body .= ucfirst($name) . ":  " . $postedValue . "\n";
      }
    }
    return $message_body;
  }

  //attempt to send email
  $emailBody = constructEmailBody();
  require './vender/php_mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  $email = new PHPMailer;
  $email->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $email->isSMTP();
  $email->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $email->SMTPAuth = true;
  $email->Username = 'email@domain.com';
  $email->Password = 'MyPassword';

  $email->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $email->Port = 587;

  $email->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
  $email->addAddress('email@domain.com');
  $email->Subject = 'Estimate Request Answers';
  $email->Body  = $emailBody;
  //try to send the message
  if($email->send()) {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Thank you! Your message was successfully submitted.'));
  } else {
    errorResponse('An unexpected error occured while attempting to send the email: ' . $email->ErrorInfo);
  }
?>
```

HTML form

```
<form role="form" id="estimateForm" method="POST">
    <div class="col-xs-12 contact-information">
        <div class="form-group">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Contact Information</legend>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
                    <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
                    <label class="control-label" for="address">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Enter Address">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <label class="control-label" for="phone">Phone Number</label> 
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">
                    <label class="control-label" for="contact-time">Preferred Contact Time</label>
                    <select class="selectpicker contact-time" id="contact-time" name="contact-time" title="Preferred Contact Time">
                        <option value="Morning">Morning (9-11am)</option>
                        <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon (11-2pm)</option>
                        <option value="Evening">Evening (2-5pm)</option>
                    </select>
                    <label class="control-label" for="contact-method">Preferred Contact Method</label>
                    <select class="selectpicker contact-method" id="contact-method" name="contact-method" title="Preferred Contact Method">
                        <option>By Phone</option>
                        <option>By Email</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thank you for your time in advance and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

nothing to do with the mail code you can use a simple `str_replace()` on `$name`

or

```
if($name =='whatever'){
$name='something else';
}
```

or about 10 other options